# Using waze functions with an external app

Tags: collaboration, waze

I'd like to know if it is possibile using waze's API about the community like danger points for an external app and integrated them with some our features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Waze has strict rules concerning to who they expose the reports sent in by users. They provide a feed of reports for specific areas through the [Waze Connected Citizens Program (CCP)](https://www.waze.com/nl/ccp), but this program is generally only available for governmental institutions or road authorities. Generally the program also expects a dataflow towards Waze (road closures, for example).

That said, I don't work for Waze and I don't know all the details of the app you are working on. Depending on the type of app you are talking about, they may like to collaborate. You could always try to apply as a CCP partner and perhaps they may make an exception. Just be aware that while Waze has a lot of users, it is actually not a very big company so support queries may take a while to get a reply.

Note that it is technically possible to scrape the information from the [Waze Live Map](https://www.waze.com/livemap), but I'd strongly advice against doing that without permission as it could lead to legal actions.